# How to view specialization class bonuses have been activated/applied?

Tags: mass-effect

I have chosen Commando specialization when prompted. How do I know the specialization bonuses have been activated or applied to my talents? My talent screen still looks the same. Still shows Soldier class and talent/skills tree still looks the same. No added notes anywhere to show faster recharge bonus, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This information isn't made available in the user interface as far as I remember. It behaves in a similar manner to your original class choice, whose damage bonuses were also not exposed in the user interface.

Once you select your class specialisation, it replaces your original class in the skill tree:

[image]

You will keep all of your originally assigned skills but this still doesn't reveal the additional bonuses applied from your class specialisation.

Comment: Thanks Kalina! I didn't notice that skill row was renamed Commando. Thanks for your screenshot effort, being an old game which many would not be playing now. :-)